# Flutter Google Sign and Phone Auth error after publishing the app com.google.android.gms.common.api.b 10

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Google sign in and phone authentication were working fine in debug and release mode. But after publishing the app in play store, Google sign in produce the following error:

`com.google.android.gms.common.api.b 10`

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: did you add the release sha-1 to firebase ?

Comment: is this on Huawei devices by any chance? Or all android devices in play stores?

Answer (score 1):

> Google sign in and phone authentication were working fine in debug and release mode.

If you are absolutely sure about this, and that they debug and release keys were added to Firebase. Then the situation you are facing now can be explained by using a different key for your app store.

If you have opted in of google automatically manage signing, then it will have probably signed your app with a different signature than the one you currently have added to firebase console.

Log into your developer console, find the key being used to sign your app, and add that to Firebase, along with the existing keys.

This should\can be solved without having to publish a new release.

Comment: Thank you. I have opted for google automatically signing. I did what you said and it work. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome, Vincent. Kindly consider marking it as the correct solution to your questions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that given by Huthaifa Muayyad. I did what he said and it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding plugin and classpath to the app/build.gradle and android/build.gradle respectively. For reference, I am adding code below.

1)app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'     //add this line
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

2)android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'     //add this line
}
```

Comment: This will most likely not solve the issue, because they were working during development. So the plugins have been indeed installed, and the workflow was fine. It's something related to the signing certificates.